# Configure htaccess to symfony project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a hosting with my personal project in Symfony2 installed it inside a folder "`public_html`", then when I want to access to my project I have to write the next

`url: "mydomian.net/myprojectSymfony/web/"`, instead of "`mydomain.net`".

If I just write `mydomain.net` the server shows me the directory "`public_html`" with all folders inside him. How can I write my `.htaccess` file to solve this problem?
I tried with Redirect `301` but I don't know if the right way.

Comment: Can you show us you apache config?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach is to configure your apache vhost as explained there:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.net
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myprojectSymfony/web
    <Directory /var/www/myprojectSymfony/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```